# How to prove $\log A=V(\log A')V^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Calculating_the_logarithm_of_a_diagonalizable_matrix

Suppose $A$ is a diagonalizable matrix, how to prove $\log A=V(\log A')V^{-1}$ where V is the matrix eigenvectors of $A$ and $A'$ is the diagonal matrix of corresponding eigenvalues?

Comment: Welcome to MSE, please attach a working of your own to let us know that you tried working on this problem.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit I really did not have a good idea. I guess I must missed some properity of $V$, but in linear algebra they really did not talk much about the properity of $V$ except when constructing the transformation matrix $P$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, each column of $V$ has to be orthnormal.

Comment: Each eigenvector can always be normalized, the key to notice is that, when there is a degeneracy, it's best to find the orthonormal basis of the degenerate state as well. The reason for this was to establish $VV^{-1}=I$

Second, $A=V(A')V^{-1}$, notice in the series expansion of $log(A)$, the term $(A-I)$ can be written as follow $(V(A')V^{-1}-I)=(V(A')V^{-1}-VV^{-1})=V(A'V^{-1}-IV^{-1})=V(A'-I)V^{-1}$, where it's power $(A-I)^n=V(A'-I)^nV^{-1}$.  Notice $(A'-I)$ is a diagonal matrix.

Thus $A=V log(A')V^{-1}$ as desired.